# Loop through attributes using <xsl:for-each>

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to loop through the below XML to get a list based on attribute value. Is it possible to pass @field value as a variable to the for-each ?

Tried using `<xsl:for-each select="project[@field='author']/projectValue">` but ended up duplicating the loop for each field

sample xml

```
<Properties>
    <projects>
        <project field="author">
            <projectValue count="3">disney</projectValue>
            <projectValue count="3">mark</projectValue>
        </project>
        <project field="type">
            <projectValue count="6">news</projectValue>
            <projectValue count="31">page</projectValue>
        </project>
    </projects>
</Properties>
```

XSL

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <ul class="gta-2">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/Properties/projects" />
    </ul>
    <ul class="gta-2">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/Properties/projects"/>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match = "projects" >
    <xsl:for-each select="project/projectValue">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </li>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Output

```
<ul class="author">
    <li>disney</li>
    <li>mark</li>
    <li>news</li>
    <li>page</li>
</ul>
<ul class="type">
    <li>disney</li>
    <li>mark</li>
    <li>news</li>
    <li>page</li>
</ul>
```

Expected output

```
<ul class="author">
    <li>disney</li>
    <li>mark</li>
</ul>
<ul class="type">
    <li>news</li>
    <li>page</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using these two templates:

```
<xsl:template match = "project" >
    <ul class="{@field}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="projectValue"/>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match = "projectValue" >
    <li><xsl:value-of select="." /></li>
</xsl:template>
```

Its output is:

```
<ul class="author">
    <li>disney</li>
    <li>mark</li>
</ul>
<ul class="type">
    <li>news</li>
    <li>page</li>
</ul>
```

This is probably the most direct way of creating your desired output. There is no need to pass any attribute. Each (attribute) value is processed in the corresponding template. Direct and clear.